# How do I get BiwaScheme to run in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, scheme

I'd like to try to get [BiwaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/) to run is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), please.

The BiwaScheme page claims that all you need to do is:

```
<script src="biwascheme.js">
(display "hello, world!")
</script>
```

So I added the resource http://www.biwascheme.org/repos/release/biwascheme-min.js in JSFiddle, and the `(display ...)` in the JavaScript window.

http://jsfiddle.net/MsjMH/1/

However, nothing happens. The console error I am getting is:

```
// Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not going to turn the browser into a Scheme interpreter. You have to hook the REPL up explicitly somehow.

Comment: They've got some demo pages on the website that somehow use a textarea to collect code and then run it.

Comment: Good 1dea (sorry for the 1, my "eye" key broke)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can evaluate a string as Scheme program with BiwaScheme.Interpreter.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/TaEEN/1/

(FYI) There is also BiwaScheme-fiddle: http://blackboard.biwascheme.org/

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry to take so long to reply.

Comment: @Yutaka HAHA - The biwascheme-min.js seems to be gone from biwscheme.org Could you restore it? It is nice to have the latest version online for inclusion in scripts.